IDA Pro Dataset Merger
Are there any resources for creating a IDA Pro merger API for merging datasets that for example; have the same data but one had a struct and one has no struct, same structs but different naming conventions, merging database one with struct A & B with another database with struct C to output database with structs A, B, & C - that kind of thing.
I've seen that this is possible on IDA Teams, but we do not have this license and we wont get it, so just wondering if anyone has any resources on how to go about this on IDA Pro?
Tried various mergers through IDA Pro api and migrator documentation, but have hit a bit of a wall with the documentation and can't find any additional resources.
